# Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the error 'Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget' but I don't see where the problem is.
I have checked here for other post but don't find anything to help me.
I don't use Expanded else where than Column, Row.

(I know the function updateColour can be simplify but I'm following a course at the moment and this is where this project comes from.)

Can you please help me ? I really don't see where the error comes from.

*input_page.dart*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'reusable_card.dart';
import 'icon_content.dart';

const bottomContainerHeight = 80.0;
const activeCardColour = Color(0xFF1D1E33);
const inactiveCardColour = Color(0xFF111328);
const bottomContainerColour = Color(0xFFEB1555);

class InputPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InputPageState createState() => _InputPageState();
}

class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage> {
  Color maleCardColour = inactiveCardColour;
  Color femaleCardColour = inactiveCardColour;

  void updateColour(int gender) {
    if (gender == 1) {
      if (maleCardColour == inactiveCardColour) {
        maleCardColour = activeCardColour;
        femaleCardColour = inactiveCardColour;
      } else {
        maleCardColour = inactiveCardColour;
        femaleCardColour = activeCardColour;
      }
    } else {
      if (femaleCardColour == inactiveCardColour) {
        femaleCardColour = activeCardColour;
        maleCardColour = inactiveCardColour;
      } else {
        femaleCardColour = inactiveCardColour;
        maleCardColour = activeCardColour;
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('BMI CALCULATOR'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        updateColour(1);
                      });
                    },
                    child: ReusableCard(
                      cardChild: IconContent(
                        icon: FontAwesomeIcons.mars,
                        label: 'MALE',
                      ),
                      colour: inactiveCardColour,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        updateColour(2);
                      });
                    },
                    child: ReusableCard(
                      cardChild: IconContent(
                        icon: FontAwesomeIcons.venus,
                        label: 'Female',
                      ),
                      colour: inactiveCardColour,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ReusableCard(
              colour: activeCardColour,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: ReusableCard(
                    colour: activeCardColour,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ReusableCard(
                    colour: activeCardColour,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            color: bottomContainerColour,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
            width: double.infinity,
            height: bottomContainerHeight,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

*Reusable_card.dart*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color colour;
  final Widget? cardChild;

  ReusableCard({required this.colour, this.cardChild});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        child: cardChild,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: colour, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: how about `ReusableCard` ? can you provide snippet code of it?

Comment: The issue is coming from `ReusableCard `

Comment: I have added the code for ReusableCard :)

Comment: ReusableCard is already wrapped with Expanded Widget. You don't have to again wrap it with Expanded inside of a Row or a Column. If you don't want expanded behaviour by default, remove Expanded from ReusableCard & use Expanded only where it is required inside of Column

Comment: I removed the Expanded in ReusableCard and the error was gone. 

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the body of the scaffold, a column widget has been added and as the child of the column an expanded widget is added. Here the column has no vertical bounds. Hence the error. Please remove the expanded widget which is inside the column. If you wish to use expanded inside the column wrap the column with a sized box of certain height for example

```dart
SizedBox(
 height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
 child: Column(
   children: [
    Expanded(
      flex: 3,
      child: Container(),
    ),
    Expanded(
     flex: 2,
     child: Container (),
    )
   ]
 )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the Expanded in ReusableCard and the error was gone.

Thanks